# Shell awk - Print a position from variable

Tags: shell, awk

Here is my string that needs to be parsed.

```
line='aaa vvv ccc'
```

I need to print the values one by one.

```
no_of_users=$(echo $line| wc -w)
```

If the `no_of_users` is greater than 1 then I need to print the values one by one.

```
aaa
vvv
ccc
```

I used this script.

```
if [ $no_of_users -gt 1 ]
 then 
 for ((n=1;n<=$no_of_users;n++))
  do 
 
  -- here is my issue ##echo 'user:'$n $line|awk -F ' ' -vno="${n}" 'BEGIN { print no }'
   done
fi
```

In the `{ print no }` I have to print the value in that position.

Comment: hello Bhuvanesh, could you please do let me know if my answer has helped you here? In my answer's comment section please, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** Within single `awk` could you please try following. Where `var` is an `awk` variable which has shell variable `line` value in it.

```
awk -v var="$line" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(var,arr," ")
  if(num>1){
    for(i=1;i<=num;i++){ print arr[i] }
  }
}'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v var="$line" '                     ##Starting awk program and creating var variable which has line shell variable value in it.
BEGIN{                                   ##Starting BEGIN section of program from here.
  num=split(var,arr," ")                 ##Splitting var into array arr here. Saving its total length into variable num to check it later.
  if(num>1){                             ##Checking condition if num is greater than 1 then do following.
    for(i=1;i<=num;i++){ print arr[i] }  ##Running for loop from i=1 to till value of num here and printing arr value with index i here.
  }
}'
```

---

***2nd solution:*** Adding one more solution tested and written in GNU `awk`.

```
echo "$line" | awk -v RS= -v OFS="\n" 'NF>1{$1=$1;print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'NF>1 {OFS="\n"; $1=$1} 1' <<< "$line"
aaa
vvv
ccc
```

What it does:

- `NF>1`: If number of fields are greater than 1
- `OFS="\n"`: Set output field separator to `\n`
- `$1=$1`: Force restructure of a record
- `1`: Print a record

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
if [ $no_of_users -gt 1 ]
 then 
 for ((n=1;n<=$no_of_users;n++))
  do 
  echo 'user:'$n $(echo $line|awk -F ' ' -v x=$n '{printf $x }')
   done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep

```
echo $line | grep -o '[a-z][a-z]*'
```

Comment: The print should only take place if there is more than one name

Answer (score 0):

Using bash:

```
$ line='aaa vvv'ccc'
$ [[ $line =~ \  ]] && echo -e ${line// /\\n}
aaa
vvv
ccc

$ line=aaa
$ [[ $line =~ \  ]] && echo -e ${line// /\\n}
$
```

If you are on another shell:

```
$ line="foo bar baz" bash -c '[[ $line =~ \  ]] && echo -e ${line// /\\n}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also with `awk`:

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' OFS='\n' <<< "$line"
aaa
vvv
ccc
```

- the key is setting `OFS='\n'`

Answer (score 0):

Or a really toughie:

```
printf "%s\n" $line
```

(**note:** `$line` is *unquoted*)

`printf` will consume all words in `line` with word-splitting applied so each word is taken as a single input.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ line='aaa vvv ccc'; printf "%s\n" $line
aaa
vvv
ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Eq '[[:space:]]' <<< "$line" && xargs printf "%s\n" <<< $line
```

Do a silent grep for a space in the variable, if true, print with names on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v OFS='\n' 'NF>1{$1=$1; print}'
```

e.g.

```
$ line='aaa vvv ccc'
$ echo "$line" | awk -v OFS='\n' 'NF>1{$1=$1; print}'
aaa
vvv
ccc

$ line='aaa'
$ echo "$line" | awk -v OFS='\n' 'NF>1{$1=$1; print}'
$
```

Answer (score 0):

another golfed `awk` variation

```
$ awk 'gsub(FS,RS)'
```

only print if there is a substitution.